# CSS - How to continue on second column for UL LI for large Li

Tags: css

I have the following CSS and it works great. However, I have about 50 li . is there a way to automatically add column and display 10 per column? I tried left: float; but the look is nasty. I tried column-count: 3 with column-gap: 10px but no effect on li (just changes the width of the ul)

I have the html and css on jsFiddle if that helps.  https://jsfiddle.net/zq54cb2b/

```
#cssmenu ul li {
  padding: 7px 7px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #cce5ff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f5f9;
}
```

Comment: Which browsers and browser versions does this need to work in? http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

Comment: IE 11 is our company's default browser but they also allow chrome and mobile devices (mostly iPads)

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? If I put your css in a fiddle and add a rule for columns - here: https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/ax4g9ubk/ - it works great in all browsers.

Comment: And I say all browsers, but I don't have Edge or Safari here. All the _other_ browsers then.

Comment: Mr Lister: I updated the post and added jsFiddle with html and css .  https://jsfiddle.net/zq54cb2b/

Answer (score 0):

What about using flexbox?

```
#cssmenu ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#cssmenu ul li {
  flex: 1 0 25%;
}
```

```css
<style>
 .ms-viewheadertr
 {
   display: none;
 }
 .ms-WPHeader
 {
  background: #93BBE4!important;  
 }
 .ms-WPTitle
 {
  font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif; 
  font-size: 14px!important;  
  color: #fffef9;
  font-weight: bolder!important;
 }
 
 .ms-WPTitle A:link, .ms-WPTitle A:visited
  {
  color:#fffef9;
  text-decoration:none;
  cursor:hand;
  }
  
 #cssmenu {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   border: 0;
   position: relative;
   z-index:1;
   padding-bottom: 25px;
   font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
 }

 #cssmenu ul,
 #cssmenu ul li,
 #cssmenu ul ul,
 #cssmenu ul ul ul {
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;   
 }

 #cssmenu ul {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 397;  
   
 }

 #cssmenu ul li {
   min-height: 1px;
   line-height: 1em;
   vertical-align: middle;  

 }
  #cssmenu ul {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  #cssmenu ul li {
  flex: 1 0 25%;
  }

 #cssmenu ul li:hover {
   position: relative;
   //z-index: 99;
   cursor: default;  
 }

 #cssmenu ul ul {
   visibility: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   top: 100%;
   left: 0;
   /* z-index: 398; */
   width: 100%;   
 }

 #cssmenu ul ul ul {
   top: 0px;
   left: 99%;
 }

 #cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
   visibility: visible;
   width:170px;
 }

 #cssmenu ul ul {
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 0;
 }

 /* Custom CSS Styles */

 #cssmenu ul {
   width: 100px;   
 }

 #cssmenu ul ul {
   width: 167px;   
 }

 #cssmenu ul li {
   padding: 7px 7px;
   color: #000000;
   background-color: #cce5ff;
   //background-color:#FFF;
   //border: 1px solid red;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f5f9;
 }

 #cssmenu ul li:hover {
   background:  #cce5ff;
   color: #000;
   box-shadow:1px 1px 10px 2px #888;
 }

 #cssmenu ul a:link,
 #cssmenu ul a:visited {
   color: #000;
   text-decoration: none;   
 }

 #cssmenu ul a:hover {
   color: #000;   
 }

 #cssmenu ul a:active {
   color: #ffa500;   
 }
 
 #cssmenu ul li a:link,
 #cssmenu ul li a:visited{
   /* color: #FFFFFF; 
   outline: none!important; */
 }
 
 #cssmenu ul li a img{
   /* color: #FFFFFF; 
   outline: none!important; */
 }
 
</style>
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 100%;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <li><img alt="Countries" src="https://cdn.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/57/49/1285749.jpg" style="width: 112px; height: 117px;" /> Select Country    
              <ul>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Argentina.aspx'><span>Argentina</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_USA .aspx'><span>USA </span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_USA .aspx'><span>All others </span></a></li>
    
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Argentina.aspx'><span>Argentina</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Bahrain .aspx'><span>Bahrain </span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Belleli.aspx'><span>Belleli</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Bolivia.aspx'><span>Bolivia</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Brazil.aspx'><span>Brazil</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Canada.aspx'><span>Canada</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Chile.aspx'><span>Chile</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_China .aspx'><span>China </span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Colombia.aspx'><span>Colombia</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Dubai .aspx'><span>Dubai </span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Ecuador.aspx'><span>Ecuador</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Egypt.aspx'><span>Egypt</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Europe.aspx'><span>Europe</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Gabon .aspx'><span>Gabon </span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Hamriyah.aspx'><span>Hamriyah</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Indonesia .aspx'><span>Indonesia </span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Marine/Offshore travel.aspx'><span>Marine/Offshore travel</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Mexico.aspx'><span>Mexico</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Nigeria .aspx'><span>Nigeria </span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Oman .aspx'><span>Oman </span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Pakistan .aspx'><span>Pakistan </span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Peru .aspx'><span>Peru </span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Qatar.aspx'><span>Qatar</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Russia.aspx'><span>Russia</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Saudi Arabia.aspx'><span>Saudi Arabia</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Singapore .aspx'><span>Singapore </span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_Thailand .aspx'><span>Thailand </span></a></li>
    <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Pages/Travel/Travel_USA .aspx'><span>USA </span></a></li>

              </ul>
            </li>
          </td>
          <td>
            <li>
              <img alt="UsefulLinks" src="https://cdn.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/67/94/9236794.jpg" style="width: 112px; height: 117px;" /> Useful Links
              <ul>
                <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/crp/docs/ProjectManagement/PJM-FRM-0010.docx'><span>Travel Request Form</span></a></li>
                <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HyattExtra/Hyatt%20Extra%2069%20-%20International%20Travel%20and%20Security.pdf'><span>International Travel & Security</span></a></li>
                <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/HR/Documents/Travel/PassportChecklist.pdf'><span>Passport Checklist</span></a></li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span>P-Card Q/A</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span>Frequently Asked Questions</span></a></li>
    
              </ul>
            </li>
          </td>

          <td>
            <li>
              <img alt="Policy" src="https://cdn.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/26/57/9082657.jpg" style="width: 112px; height: 117px;" /> Policy
              <ul>
                <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/PolicyDocs/202%20Travel%20Policy%202016-0826.docx'><span>Policy 202: Travel Guidelines</span></a></li>
                <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/PolicyDocs/202-1%20Security%20Guidelines%20for%20Traveling%20Outside%20Your%20Home%20Country.doc'><span>Policy Attachment 202-1: Security Guidelines for Traveling Outside Your Home Country</span></a></li>
                <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com/PolicyDocs/202-2%20International%20Travel%20Checklist.pdf'><span>Policy Attachment 202-2: International Travel Checklist</span></a></li>
             </ul>
            </li>
          </td>
    
          <td>
                  <li><img alt="Tools" src="https://cdn.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/11/54/3361154.jpg" style="width: 112px; height: 117px; text-align: center;" /> Tools & Resources
                  <ul>
     <li><a href='http://www.xe.com/travel-expenses-calculator/'><span>Currency Converter</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='http://www.google.com/world'><span>Mileage Calculation</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com'><span>Tips for Expense Reporting</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='https://inside.nov.com'><span>Receipts</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='http://travel.state.gov'><span>Travel Warnings</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='http://www.flightview.com/TravelTools'><span>Flight Tracker Tool</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='http://www.intellicast.com/National'><span>National Weather</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='http://quickaid.com'><span>Airport Information Directories</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='http://cibtvisas.com'><span>Visa Requirements</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='http://www.flightview.com/TravelTools'><span>Mobile Phone - Roaming/Charges</span></a></li>
     
                    </ul>
                  </li>
           </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Can the sort be where first column would show A through L and 2nd column will pick up the rest M thru Z